# Cx_freeze error lost sys.stdin

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

This is a problem that has been bothering me for a while. I have looked it up, but found no answer. I have also tried figuring it out myself, but have not succeeded. Whenever I create and try to freeze a program with the `input()` function in it I get the same error. 
[image]

I have tried running the `.exe` in command prompt but I get the same error. My `setup.py` script is below.

```
import cx_Freeze, sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

exe=Executable(
     script="input.py",
     base="Win32Gui",

     )
includefiles=[]
includes=["re"]
excludes=[]
packages=[]
setup(

     version = "0",
     description = "No Description",
     author = "Anthony",
     name = "0",
     options = {'build_exe': {'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}},
     executables = [exe]
     )
```

And my short test script:

```
import sys,re
input('input')
```

Is this a problem I can fix, or do I just have to work without the `input()` function? I am using Python 3.2, on windows seven, with the corresponding cx_freeze version.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `Win32GUI` base is designed for Windows GUI programs - i.e. they run in windows, not at a command prompt. So there's no stdin, and you can't use `input()`.

If you want to create a console program, set `base='Console'` (or `base=None`, since Console is the default).

Comment: Where should I add the "base='console' " keyword, to make it run in the console?